# Is there any way moderators can view the "actual reputation score" of a suspended user, other than from the flags dashboard?

Tags: support, reputation, moderator-tools, account-suspension, hidden-features

Users who are suspended have their reputation score reduced to 1 for the duration of the suspension. For moderators, sometimes it may be helpful to know the "actual" reputation score of the user, what it would be if they weren't suspended. This is possible to see from the moderator flags dashboard (`/admin/dashboard`) if one of the user's posts has a currently active flag: the reputation appearing next to their name in the dashboard is **1<sup>*</sup>** and hovering over the star gives this tooltip:

[image]

Clicking the star then changes the displayed reputation to their "actual" score (and there's no way to change it back except by refreshing the page).

It's interesting that this ability is given to moderators, but it seems odd if that's the *only* way mods can get this info displayed. **Is there any other hidden way for mods to see suspended users displayed with their "actual" reputation?** (I don't count "hovering over the reputation graph on their activity tab", since that works for anyone, mod or not, and it's not very reliable when they're a high-rep user with years of activity, as it's hard to pinpoint the exact end of the graph to get the correct value.)

Comment: Devil’s advocate: if they’re a high rep user does the *exact* reputation really matter? For Jon Skeet his reputation will have changed between the time you read the number and the time your brain registered the number. Also how many high-rep users are getting suspended? I feel like the reputation graph is plenty sufficient … I don’t know the design intention behind this star behavior but it seems superfluous and Easter egg-y to me.

Comment: I served as a moderator for several years and I’ve spent the past 20 minutes struggling to think of a scenario where knowing a suspended user’s ballpark (never mind accurate-to-the-second) reputation was important or even curiosity-satisfying. I’m coming up empty so far. That said, I can’t argue for it to be hidden from moderators, either, but in the list of things for devs to work on, given the data is in the rep graph, I’d put this pretty low.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Note this isn't a feature request, and I agree it's not worth dev time to make this figure easier for moderators to find. I'm just asking whether it is (already) visible anywhere else in the existing moderator tools.

Comment: Understood, I guess in my head I’m trying to pre-empt any piling on for it to _become_ a feature request. :-)

Comment: Well, capture the request sent to the server when clicking the star, and send it manually from browser console to see the actual rep. Probably some plain POST request with parameters, and someone can make it as userscript.

Comment: I understood a few of those words, @Shadow. Not many.

Comment: Fair, lol. Would have better luck asking one of the SO mods to take a look and write such userscript, if they want. :)

Comment: Why are you wanting something extra to be in the mod tools? The user's actual reputation prior to the suspension is available to everybody, even if not logged in, just by looking at the user's reputation graph on their activity page. I know you've said that's not what you want, but I find it fairly easy to just hover over the end of that graph.

Comment: @Makyen As mentioned above, I'm not asking for something extra, just asking for support with existing functionality - is there something else I've missed in the mod tools?

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard indeed, it's a POST call to `/admin/actual-reputation` with the `userId` and your `fkey` as URL encoded form data.

Comment: @Glorfindel so should be simple (?) for those who already now their ways with userscripts to turn this into something triggered with a button. Is there mod-only version of SOUP? ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The method I've always used is going to the user history (Mod menu on the user profile, then Info, then History).

This page includes all the "moderator recalcs rep" events for the user, which is just all the automated reputation recalcs that have been performed on the profile. Each one lists the old rep and the new rep values for the recalc.

When a user is suspended at the time of the recalc, the numbers look a little different. The new rep will always be 1 (because they're suspended) and the old rep will actually be the recalculated value that their reputation *would be* if they were not suspended.

Obviously this isn't their perfectly accurate reputation, because it will only record a new value when a recalc is performed and new events could have occurred since the last recalc. But we do still do recalcs for suspended users and they'll continue populating there throughout their suspension.

The value is otherwise not recorded anywhere in the system. The link in the flags dashboard is actually a special path that allows moderators to do a reputation recalc for the profile without saving the value, which is a bit of a heavy-handed and expensive approach to finding that information. If it were ever expanded to other areas, we'd probably want to modify it to just look up the most recent recalc event for that profile and return that value instead of doing all the calculations right then.

It will give you a general idea, which is good enough given there's not much need for knowing the *exact* value.

Comment: I actually didn't know about the flags dashboard option, I always just go straight to the user history page!